# How can i search multiple numbers from a Arraylist or Random Number?

Tags: c#

i have a list of 10 numbers.
When i click the button, IF the CheckBox + the number

```
//form.cs

Random rnd = new Random();
int theNumber = rnd.Next(1,11);

if (checkBox1to5.Checked == true && theNumber == 1 || theNumber == 2...)
{
    //What is the more simple way to code this?
}

elseif (checkBox6to10.Checked == true && theNumber == 6 || theNumber == 7...)
{
    //AND also, would it be any different if i was searching the number from a Array List, rather then a random generated number?

}
```

Comment: So....what is your question?

Comment: if (checkBox1to5.Checked && (theNumber >= 1 && theNumber <= 5))

Comment: @Kevin don't really need the extra paranthesis though

Comment: Yeah, I put those in just for readability, it will work fine without them. So the OP could easily see how the changes I suggested match up to what he is already doing.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just to *simplify* your code:

```
// do not re-create Random, it can make sequence being badly skewed
// create Random just once
private static Random rnd = new Random();

...

int theNumber = rnd.Next(1, 11);

if (checkBox1to5.Checked && theNumber <= 5) {
  ...
}
else if (checkBox6to10.Checked && theNumber >= 6) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following. Hope it helps:

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int theNumber = rnd.Next(1,11);
        int[] intarray = {5, 6, 7, 8}

        if (checkBox1to5.Checked == true && theNumber > 0 && theNumber < 6 )
        {
        }

        else if (checkBox6to10.Checked == true && theNumber > 5 && theNumber < 12)
        {
        }

        // For array List
        foreach(int num in intarray)
        {
            if (checkBox1to5.Checked == true && num > 0 && num < 6 )
            {
            }

            else if (checkBox6to10.Checked == true && num > 5 && num < 12)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could just do checkBox1to5.Checked instead of having them equal true

Comment: @Jetti you absolutely can and probably you should.